# angularjs getting value from scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a pagination directive for my results and I can't seem to get over this problem. I have the following code (coffeescript):

```
window.pagination_services = angular.module("pagination_services", [])
    .directive('paginate', ->
        {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '../../assets/app/partials/services/pagination.html',
            scope: true,
            link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
                console.log $scope.results
        }
    )
```

As you can see I have a console.log on `$scope.results` which returns:

```
e
    pagination: Object
        current_page: 1
        per_page: 20
        total_entries: 4097
        __proto__: Object
    sales: Array[20]
    __proto__: e
```

I need to be able to access the value of that pagination object. Something like:

```
$scope.results.pagination.current_page
```

but, no matter what I try, I get undefined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your directive depends on a controller which contains the "results" and you would want to inject that into this directive as a dependancy.

Say the controller is called as ResultsController

You might want to do something like

```
.directive('paginate', ->
        {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            require : '^ResultsController'
            templateUrl: '../../assets/app/partials/services/pagination.html',
            scope: true,
            link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
                console.log $scope.results
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope. the controller is a parent of this directive so I inherit it's attributes. I'll post the solution. It's all about async. My object was a httppromise that's why I couldn't fetch it. I can't answer my own question unfortunately

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have come to same conclusion ... but you should probably create a watch on your results [(see scope doc)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) and check for new value before accessing.